# Perl and SSH communication

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I need a ssh communication between a client that runs in a Perl script and a host in a linux pc.
The Perl script will establish ssh communication,
send a command to the host to run a remote .py script that is stored in the linux machine,
and then send commands to the python script, that will execute specific actions, and wait for next command to execute.

So far, I couldn’t find a way to do it. Any suggestions?
**Plus, I need a solution with “use Net::OpenSSH” and not with “use Net::SSH::Perl”**

The python script goes like that:

```
import sys

def process_command(command):
    if command == "cmd1":
        sys.stdout.write("cmd1 executed\n")
    elif command == "cmd2":
        sys.stdout.write("cmd2 executed \n")
    elif command == "exit":
        sys.stdout.write("exit!\n")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Invalid command\n")

for line in sys.stdin:
    # Remove any leading/trailing whitespaces and newline characters
    command=line.strip()
    process_command(command)
    # send an ack message to Perl client
    sys.stdout.write("OK")
    sys.stdout.flush()  # Ensure the output is immediately flushed
```

when I run it from the linux’s terminal, it seems to work.

The Perl subroutines go like that:

```
use Net::OpenSSH; 
sub _openSshConnection
{   
    my $self = shift;
    my $success = 0;
 
    if (!defined $self->{args}->{ctrlHost} ||
        !defined $self->{args}->{ctrlUser} ||
        !defined $self->{args}->{ctrlPass})
    {   
        $self->_DEBUG("Hostname & User credentials not defined.");  
        $success = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $self->_DEBUG("Establising SSH connection to %s.", $self->{args}->{ctrlHost});
        my $sshDir = UBX::Utils::getOpenSSHCtlDir();
        my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new( $self->{args}->{ctrlHost},
                                user => $self->{args}->{ctrlUser},
                                password => $self->{args}->{ctrlPass},
                                master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", '-X']
                                ctl_dir => $sshDir,
                                strict_mode => 0
                                );
        $success = $ssh;
        if ($ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error) 
        {   
            $success = 0;
        }       
    }
    $self->_DEBUG("SSH connection:".$success);
    return $success;
}

##########################################################################################
sub python_Start
{
my $self = shift;
    my $success = 0;
    my @commands = ('cmd1','cmd2');
my $cmd = 'python3 /path/script.py';
$self->{ssh}->system($cmd);
```

Like that if I go to my Perl terminal, write a command (cmd1), it is executed, and I receive in the terminal also the messages sent from python. But how do I write and read the commands and responses inside my script?
I want something like:

```
foreach my $command (@commands) {
    # send command1
    # get ack
        # then send the following command 
        # etc
}
```

Comment: The [Net::OpenSSH](https://perldoc.pl/Net::OpenSSH) documentation mentions the `capture` method.

Comment: `->capture` if you don't need to provide input via stdin. `->open2` or `->open3`, plus a `IO::Select->select` loop if you do.

Answer (score 3):

> But how do I write and read the commands and responses inside my script?

You could try using [`open_ex()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Net::OpenSSH-methods) to open pipes for reading and writing from the python script. For example,

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
    $host,
    user     => $user,
    port     => $port,
    password => $password,
);
$ssh->error and
  die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;

my @cmd = ('python3', 'script.py');
my %opts = (
    stdin_pipe   => 1,
    stdout_pipe  => 1,
    stderr_pipe  => 1,
);

my ($in, $out, $err, $pid) = $ssh->open_ex(\%opts, @cmd);
say "PID = $pid";
my @commands = ('cmd1', 'cmd2', 'exit');
for my $cmd (@commands) {
    say $in $cmd;
    my $result = <$out>;
    chomp $result;
    say "got result: '$result'";
    sleep 1;
}
my $kid = waitpid $pid, 0;  # reap the slave SSH process
#say "waitpid returned: $kid";
```

Note that in general you should use [`IO::Select`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Select) to avoid deadlocks when trying to read from a process that might be expecting input before it writes anything.

### Edit

To handle possible deadlocks you could replace the `for` loop with:

```
# .... <-- previous code as before
use IO::Select;
my $timeout = 5;
use constant {
    READ    => 0x1,
    WRITE   => 0x2,
    TIMEOUT => 0x4,
    ERROR   => 0x8,
    EOF     => 0x10,
};

my $cmd = shift @commands;
while (1) {
    my ($status, $child_output) = read_or_write_data($in, $out, $cmd, $timeout);
    if ($status & READ) {
        say "got result: '$child_output'";
    }
    if ($status & WRITE) {
        say "Sendt command: '$cmd'";
        $cmd = shift @commands;
    }
    if ($status & TIMEOUT) {
        say "Read/write from child timed out";
        last;
    }
    if ($status & ERROR) {
        say "Read/write from child failed";
        last;
    }
    if ($status & EOF) {
        say "Child process read handle EOF";
        last;
    }
}

my $kid = waitpid $pid, 0;  # reap the slave SSH process
#say "waitpid returned: $kid";

sub read_or_write_data {
    my ($writer, $reader, $cmd, $timeout) = @_;
    my $status = 0;
    my $sel_writers = IO::Select->new( $writer );
    my $sel_readers = IO::Select->new( $reader );
    my $child_output = '';
    local $! = 0; # Clear ERRNO such that we can differentiate between timeout and other errors
    my @sel_result = IO::Select::select( $sel_readers, $sel_writers, undef, $timeout );
    if (!@sel_result) {
        if ($!) {
            say "Select() failed with error: $!";
            $status |= ERROR;
        }
        else {
            $status |= TIMEOUT;
        }
    }
    my @read_ready = @{ $sel_result[0] };
    my @write_ready = @{ $sel_result[1] };
    if ( @write_ready ) {
        if ($cmd) {
            say $writer $cmd;
            $status |= WRITE;
        }
    }
    if ( @read_ready ) {
        $child_output = <$reader>;
        if (!defined $child_output) {
            $status |= EOF;
        }
        else {
            chomp $child_output;
            $status |= READ;
        }
    }
    return ($status, $child_output);
}
```

Comment: 2) `->open3` is the same as `->open_ex` with the options you provided, so it's a lot shorter. As the docs say, you shouldn't have to use `->open_ex`.

Comment: 3) But since the program is interactive, you probably need the `stdin_pty` instead of `stdin_pipe`, `stdout_pty` instead of `stdout_pipe`, and `stderr_pty` instead of `stderr_pipe`. Or just use `->open3pty`. Again, you shouldn't be using `->open_ex`.

Comment: @ikegami *"Your solution can deadlock*" : Thanks for the comments! I have updated my answer with a select loop to handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have code which does this very thing.  Here's the gist of it.

1. Create a connection

```
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new( $host, %args ); 
    $ssh->error and die("error");
```

2. Create a PTY that [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) can use

```
    my ( $pty, undef ) = $ssh->open2pty( $remote_command );
```

3. Connect [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) to it

```
    my $exp = Expect->init( $pty );
```

4. Profit

Answer (score 1):

One way, using `capture` from [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Net::OpenSSH; 

my $host = shift or die "Usage: $0 hostname\n";

#my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, %ctor_opts);  # provide password etc
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host); 
die "ssh failed: ", $ssh->error if $ssh->error; 

my @ret = $ssh->capture('ls -l'); 
chomp @ret;
say for @ret[0..2], '...', @ret[-2,-1]; 

say '';

@ret = $ssh->capture('ls | head -5'); 

print for @ret;
```

See documentation for how to provide the password via options to the constructor.

Comment: While the OP didn't mention the need to provide data via the program's stdin, the program they showed reads from stdin. Worse, it might be interactive. (in, out, int, out)

Comment: @ikegami  Good point, I can certainly do more here.  (It appears that this program needs to feed stdin of the python target program)  Will edit when I catch a minute, thanks